# Layout of a Linux process's "user" area

Tags: linux, process

ptrace(2) provides tools to modify a Linux process's "user" area (search http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace for PTRACE_POKEUSER).

What does this memory region look like?  Where can I find the documentation of its layout?

Thanks!

P.S. I realize the area contains things like signal actions, accounting information and a system stack, but I'm curious of the exact format. =)

Comment: My goal is to set vmem pages permissions (as if the controlled process called `mprotect`).  Just curious if that information is in this "user" area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under PEEKUSER, the man page for ptrace says

> Reads a word at offset addr in the child's USER area, which holds the registers and other information about the process (see `<sys/user.h>`).

So look in `/usr/include/sys/user.h` to see the definition of `struct user`. To access things from there you'll want to use an offsetof macro to find the right offset to read/write the data you want.

Comment: My GNU version is grossly undocumented.  But thanks, this is a start!